# Average of array column of two dataframes and find the maximum index in pyspark

Tags: dataframe, pyspark

I want to Combine the column values of two dataframe after performing some operations to create a new dataframe in pyspark. The columns of each dataframe are vectors with integer values. The operations done are taking the average of each values in the vectors of the dataframe and finding the index of the maximum element of the new vectors created.

Dataframe1:

```
       |id| |value1 |
       |:.| |:......|
       | 0| |[0,1,2]|
       | 1| |[3,4,5]|
```

Dataframe2:

```
        |id| |value2 |
        |:.| |:......|
        | 0| |[1,2,3]|
        | 1| |[4,5,6]|
```

Dataframe3:

```
         |value3       |
         |:............|
         |[0.5,1.5,2.5]|
         |[3.5,4.5,5.5]|
```

Dataframe4:

```
         |value4|
         |:.....|
         |2     |
         |2     |
```

Dataframe3 is obtained by taking the average of each elements of each vectors of dataframe 1 and 2 i.e.: first vector of dataframe3 [0.5,1.5,2.5] is obtained by [0+1/2,1+2/2,2+3/2]. Dataframe4 is obtained by taking the index of maximum value of each vector.i.e; Take first vector of dataframe3[0.5,1.5,2.5] maximum value is 2.5 and it occurs at index 2 so first element in Dataframe4 is 2. How we can implement this in pyspark .

V1:

```
           +--------------------------------------+---+
           |p1                                    |id |
           +--------------------------------------+---+
           |[0.01426862, 0.010903089, 0.9748283]  |0  |
           |[0.068229124, 0.89613986, 0.035630997]|1  |
           +--------------------------------------+---+
```

V2:

```
           +-------------------------+---+
           |p2                       |id |
           +-------------------------+---+
           |[0.0, 0.0, 1.0]          |0  |
           |[2.8160464E-27, 1.0, 0.0]|1  |
           +-------------------------+---+
```

when df3 = v1.join(v2,on="id") is used

df3=
this is what I get

```
           +-------------------------------------+---------------+
           |p1                                   |p2             |
           +-------------------------------------+---------------+
           |[0.02203844, 0.010056663, 0.9679049] |[0.0, 0.0, 1.0]|
           |[0.039553806, 0.015186918, 0.9452593]|[0.0, 0.0, 1.0]|
           +-------------------------------------+---------------+
```

and  when

```
     df3 = df3.withColumn( "p3", F.expr("transform(arrays_zip(p1, p2), x -> (x.p1 + x.p2) / 2)"),)
     df4 = df3.withColumn("p4",F.expr("array_position(p3, array_max(p3))"))
```

were p3 is the average value .I  get  all values of df4 as zero

Comment: do you need intermediate state of dataframe 3 ? or just the final state in dataframe 4 ?

Comment: I didn't join the dataframes. I have only dataframe 1 and dataframe2 . I like to know how to obtain dataframe 3 and 4

Comment: @Steven. yes I like to know how to obtain dataframe 3 and 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I recreate your test data :

```py
a = [
    [0, [0,1,2]],
    [1, [3,4,5]],
]
b = ["id", "value1"]
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(a,b)

c = [
    [0, [1,2,3]],
    [1, [4,5,6]],
]
d = ["id", "value2"]
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(c,d)
```

then, I process the data :

1. join

```
df3 = df1.join(df2, on="id")

df3.show()
+---+---------+---------+                                                       
| id|   value1|   value2|
+---+---------+---------+
|  0|[0, 1, 2]|[1, 2, 3]|
|  1|[3, 4, 5]|[4, 5, 6]|
+---+---------+---------+
```

2. create the average array

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, types as T

@F.udf(T.ArrayType(T.FloatType()))
def avg_array(array1, array2):
    return list(map(lambda x: (x[0] + x[1]) / 2, zip(array1, array2)))

df3 = df3.withColumn("value3", avg_array(F.col("value1"), F.col("value2")))

# OR without UDF 

df3 = df3.withColumn(
    "value3",
    F.expr("transform(arrays_zip(value1, value2), x -> (x.value1 + x.value2) / 2)"),
)

df3.show()
+---+---------+---------+---------------+                                       
| id|   value1|   value2|         value3|
+---+---------+---------+---------------+
|  0|[0, 1, 2]|[1, 2, 3]|[0.5, 1.5, 2.5]|
|  1|[3, 4, 5]|[4, 5, 6]|[3.5, 4.5, 5.5]|
+---+---------+---------+---------------+
```

3. get the index (the `array_position` start at 1, you can do a `-1` if necessary)

```
df4 = df3.withColumn("value4",F.expr("array_position(value3, array_max(value3))"))

df4.show()
+---+---------+---------+---------------+------+                                
| id|   value1|   value2|         value3|value4|
+---+---------+---------+---------------+------+
|  0|[0, 1, 2]|[1, 2, 3]|[0.5, 1.5, 2.5]|     3|
|  1|[3, 4, 5]|[4, 5, 6]|[3.5, 4.5, 5.5]|     3|
+---+---------+---------+---------------+------+
```

Comment: `df3` could be also calculated without a `UDF`, example: `df3 = df3.withColumn("value3", F.expr("transform(arrays_zip(value1, value2), x -> (x.value1 + x.value2) / 2)"))`

Comment: @Anu and you see that a join is needed

Comment: @Steven Yes. Actually my array values contains floating point values which contains scientific notation exponent numbers . For that arrays dataframe when I perform union I am not getting the correct result. Could you please help. I have edited my question.